# HTML & CSS - Background image overflow?

Tags: html, css, blurry

so I have a div with another div inside it placed in the center of my page and i want the background of that div to be the size of the entire window but i want it to only show the background in the div not outside it.

```
.boxblur {
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:27%;
    left:25%;
    right:25%;
    bottom:45%;
    min-height:289px;
    max-height:289px;
    min-width:400px;
    font-size:33px;
    color:white;
    opacity:1;
    transition:6s all;
    -webkit-transition:6s all;
    }



.insideblur{
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    transition:1s all;
    -webkit-transition:1s all;
    background-image: url('pics/back.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    }
```

I have inside blur nested inside boxblur. I've tried quite a few different things and nothing will keep the blur inside the box. for

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what I would do:

Let say you have a `div` of `id` `background-img` for example.(in this case the background is an image)

```
<div id="background-img">
</div>
```

In your **CSS** file:

```
#background-img {
         background: url('yourimage.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

and then you can add any styling you want. Hope that helps.

Comment: I had tried using cover before but I actually added fixed to the positioning and that seemed to fixed it

EDIT: the edges are still too transparent. I want the edges of the outter div to be hard

Comment: What do you mean by hard?

Comment: so the inner div is meant to be against the edges of the outer div so that the edge of the outer div creates a solid line. right now it's a very soft edge meaning it's blurred to the edge and kind of fades from the divs background to the background of the webpage

EDIT: it's kinda hard to explain with out images

Comment: Did you try to add a border style like so `{border: 2px solid;}`

Comment: that made it worse actually.

Comment: Then I might not be getting the whole picture... could you edit your post and include a screenshot of what you have.

Answer (score 0):

change the

```
.insideblur{
position:absolute;
display:block;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
transition:1s all;
-webkit-transition:1s all;
background-image: url('pics/back.jpg');
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
-moz-filter: blur(10px);
-o-filter: blur(10px);
-ms-filter: blur(10px);
filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Fixed on fixed doesn't work well. 
if not already, put the .insideBlur inside the .boxBlur

like so:

```
<div class = "boxBlur">
    <div class = "insideBlur"> 
       STUFF....
    </div>
</div>
```